# Find page title in selenium-python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm currently using this method to refresh the page when a URL is loaded.

```
if driver.current_url == URL: driver.refresh()
```

Is there an API method I can use so that if the page title matches a specific word then driver.refresh()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `driver.title`

```
if "Python" in driver.title:
    driver.refresh()
```

Or, ofc, strict equality:

```
if "Python" == driver.title:
    driver.refresh()
```

As a tip, you can inspect what else `driver` contains, by printing the following function call to the console: `print(dir(driver))`. You'll see stuff like `current_url`, `title`, `refresh` and so on, and might save you time.